# Countdown Timer in PHP restarts

Tags: javascript, php, session, timer

I'm writing a countdown timer using javascript in a php-mysql project, the countdown timer works correctly, but the problem is that when the user interacts with the game, the timer restarts. Should I do something with php sessions?

Any ideas?

```
     <div>Time left = <span id="timer"></span></div>
     <script>
       document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 01 + ":" + 00;
       startTimer();

       function startTimer() {
         var presentTime = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;
         var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
         var m = timeArray[0];
         var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
         if(s==59){m=m-1}
         if(m<0){alert('You lose,click reset')}                      
         document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =m + ":" + s;
         setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
       }

       function checkSecond(sec) {
       if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) {sec = "0" + sec}; // add zero in front 
       of numbers < 10
       if (sec < 0) {sec = "59"};
       return sec;
       }
     </script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: "when a user make something on screen timer restarts"?

Comment: its a hangman game, when a user tap a letter for a word to guess, timer restarts.

Comment: I guess you're detecting that a letter was hit, and refresh the whole page?

Comment: yes i use sessions in the game, can i add php sessions in js code?

Comment: I see. There's no super easy solution to this. You either should avoid reloading the whole page, so the javascript timer can keep running, or you have to send the timer information to PHP, together with the key that was hit, to set the timer to correct initial time. I would choose the first method. Look into a technology called "AJAX" which is normally used for this.

Comment: Third alternative: You could also store the timer information in local storage.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to send info in php..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments to the main question, there are ways you can "jury rig" this, but I'm not entirely sure its the perfect solution for you.

When the user first initiates the game and you redirect them with a php action, I'm guessing this starts the initial timer, and subsequent interactions with the game also resets the timer also.

You could initiate a php session and save the start time of the game into a php session variable. Then when the page loads again, check for the existence of the session/variable, if it is set, then us it to do whatever you need it to as the difference between the current time and the start time of the game will tell you how long the game has been going for.

You can pass variables from php to JS with:

```
let js_start_time_variable = "<?=php_start_time_variable?>";
```

This solution is not pretty. I would recommend using something like vuejs to keep the entire game in a single page application without using page refreshes to php.